# How do i isolate a particular part of the output of a powershell command?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to separate a very select part of a powershell command output. The output looks like this [*Picture of Output*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWtZr.jpg). What i would like to do is remove the top and bottom lines and isolate the number and assign it to a array. I have in my research so far been able to remove the top line. The code that i have so far is this:

```
echo working
cd C:\Users\elias\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools
./adb kill-server
./adb start-server
$a = ./adb devices
$lines = $a[1..$a.count]
$lines
Start-Sleep -s 10
```

With this code i omit the first line but keep the blank line and the additional label on the number. Is there anyway to assign the number to a separate array. Note in some situations when i use this code there will be more lines similar to the one with the number. Therefore it is possible that i will need to keep multiple of the numbers in an array.

I would appreciate the help in any way. i have looked all over this website and have not found an example.

Many thanks,

Elias

Answer (score 0):

You're close. Use the range operator `..`, and calculate the right index.

```
$a = 'first line', 1, 2, 'last line'
$b = $a[1..(($a.Count) - 2)]
$b
--
1
2
```

I don't have direct access to PowerShell at the moment, so I'm using an online PowerShell interpreter. I'm not sure how much to trust it yet.

---

```
$a = 'first line', '1babhdjf','12845783', '89872hjdf', 'last line'
$lines = $a[1..(($a.Count) - 2)]
$lines

1babhdjf
12845783
89872hjdf
```

Comment: Hi i think you might have misunderstood me. I would like all the numbers from each line to be there own entry in the array. Example {1babhdjf,12845783,89872hjdf}. I do appreciate your help. I am a novice to powershell scripts so if you could give a little more instruction it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: @EliasRC: *"I would like all the numbers from each line to be there (sic) own entry in the array."* They are. Added a more explicit example. If it's wrong, be more explicit about your input. Simple code, not a link to a graphic. Like my first line of code, please.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this in 1 line of code

```
$a = ./adb devices | where {$_ -match '(.*)device$'} | % {$Matches[1]}
```

The command where {$_ -match '(.*)device$'} will get you all lines that ends with devices

For each line that ends with device, the command % {$Matches[1]} will get you the first element - which is the serial number of the device

Comment: Hello Thanks for responding. I tried you response and i got a line with the number and the label device. It is not omitting the device label. I copied it exactly. Is there something im doing wrong?

Comment: but it did get rid of the extra lines so thanks for that i appreciate that

Comment: I updated answer .. please try again .. please provide the output of this command. I am currently on mac so unable to test myself